# Correct permissions and ownership, still get "operation not permitted" with chmod

Tags: shell, permissions, chmod

I'm getting "operation not permitted" even though I am in the group that owns the folder (and parent folder).

```
[acoder@box documents]$ chmod 770 customer123/
chmod: changing permissions of 'customer123/': Operation not permitted
```

Overview of directory:

```
[acoder@box documents]$ tree ../documents/

documents/
└── customer123
    ├── c1.pdf 
    ├── c2.pdf
    └── c3.pdf
```

Ownership & permissions:

```
[acoder@box documents]$ ll ../documents/
drwxrwx---. 5 apache salesteam 41 Apr 30  2019

[acoder@box documents]$ ll ../documents/customer123/
-rwxrwx---. 1 apache salesteam 32300 Apr 30  2019 c1.pdf
-rwxrwx---. 1 apache salesteam 31301 Apr 30  2019 c2.pdf
-rwxrwx---. 1 apache salesteam 33300 Apr 30  2019 c3.pdf
```

User `acoder` is in group `salesteam`:

```
cat /etc/group

acoder:x:1000:
salesteam:x:1001:acoder
```

I'm at a loss why I am getting `Operation not permitted` here.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

From the syscall chmod man page...

```
The effective UID of the calling process must match the owner of the file, or the process must be privileged
```

In other words, only the owner or an id with raised permissions can change permissions. Why this is also not in the exe's man page, I do not know.